# Could plasma be pressurized? Is there a state of matter beyond plasma?

Tags: electromagnetism, pressure, plasma-physics

I would like to know if it is possible to pressurize plasma with electromagnetic force. if you wanted to pressurize any plasma it could not be done with a solid container as the plasma would lose charge to my understanding. Could plasma be contained in one space by an elctromagnetical container and be pressurized by it?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look of how the ITER fusion reactor [contains the plasma](http://www.iter.org/sci/plasmaconfinement).

> Plasmas consist of charged particles—positive nuclei and negative electrons—that can be shaped and confined by magnetic forces. Like iron filings in the presence of a magnet, particles in the plasma will follow magnetic field lines. The magnetic field acts as a recipient that is not affected by heat like an ordinary solid container.

There exists the [quark gluon plasma,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_gluon_plasma) whose existence  is being explored at the [LHC.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LHC)

> A quark–gluon plasma (QGP) or quark soup[1](http://www.iter.org/sci/plasmaconfinement) is a (possible) phase of quantum chromodynamics (QCD) which exists at extremely high temperature and/or density. This phase consists of asymptotically free quarks and gluons, which are several of the basic building blocks of matter.

Comment: sweet!thanks for the reply :) I'm a total noob so pardon my blatant questions!